# Freeform 4.2.5 bcc notifications not sending

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, email

I have an old site running EE v2.11.3 and Freeform Pro v4.2.5. I know it needs updating but I can't at the moment for... reasons.

I have a freeform form that notifies admins on submission.

- admin_notify email is sent OK
- admin_cc_notify emails are sent OK
- admin_bcc_notify emails are NOT sent

I've checked and double checked the form parameters.

I have email logs turned on in Freeform but no errors.

EE email is sent through sendgrid. In the activity feed of the sendgrid control panel I can see the admin and cc emails but nothing at all for bcc emails. No errors, nothing, it looks like they aren't being triggered by Freeform at all.

Parameters are like this (addresses changed).

```
admin_notify="aaa@test.com"
admin_cc_notify="bbb@test.com"
admin_bcc_notify="ccc@test.com"
admin_notification_template="find_local_members_to_admin"
notify_admin="yes"
```

Any ideas what else I can test or if anyone has come across this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common for transactional email services to not support BCCs. Generally these services send to each address in the `to` field separately anyway, so CCing and BCCing aren't often necessary anyway.

You may want to verify with SendGrid that this actually works.

Comment: Yep, confirmed, SendGrid sends them all as individual emails anyway so bcc is not needed. Thanks.